# Can I block a file execution with AppLocker?

Tags: windows, security, applocker

We currently use a combination of a regular and an "advanced/fancy" endpoint malware protection,  in the advanced malware app, I can feed a SHA256 hash of an executable into the advanced platform and it will block execution of the given executable.

Can I do the same (blacklisting, not whitelisting) with AppLocker?

Comment: Yes, you can block/prevent/deny executables with Applocker, providing that the client OS supports Applocker.

Comment: @joeqwerty Why as a comment and not an answer?

Comment: Because it's probably not what OP actually had a question about, but it does literally fulfil the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can block/prevent/deny executables with Applocker, providing that the client OS supports Applocker.

Comment: Thanks!  To note, AppLocker seems to [calculate some crazy hash of "it's own."](http://superuser.com/questions/882648/why-are-the-sha256-hashes-used-by-applocker-different-to-other-generators)  Sort of annoying, but c'est la vi.